# apt-get install -y mono-complete goes into sleep for hrs on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: apt, 15.10, mono

I am trying to install mono-complete on a server using automated python script.

what i am seeing is `apt-get install -y mono-complete` installation stucks for long time. when observed process using `ps aux | grep apt`. i see process status is sleep

```
root      1560  0.0  0.0   4476   772 ?        S    23:22   0:00 /bin/sh -c sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get -y install mono-complete
root      1591  0.0  0.0  51292  3724 ?        S    23:22   0:00 sudo apt-get -y install mono-complete
root      1592  0.1  0.2  68904 42916 ?        S    23:22   0:01 apt-get -y install mono-complete
root      1597  0.3  0.0  28876  4980 ?        S    23:22   0:02 /usr/lib/apt/methods/http
root      1598  0.3  0.0  28876  5132 ?        S    23:22   0:03 /usr/lib/apt/methods/http
```

process status shows this

```
Name:   sudo
State:  S (sleeping)
Tgid:   1591
Ngid:   0
Pid:    1591
PPid:   1560
TracerPid:      0
Uid:    0       0       0       0
Gid:    0       0       0       0
FDSize: 64
Groups: 0
NStgid: 1591
NSpid:  1591
NSpgid: 1162
NSsid:  1162
VmPeak:    51332 kB
VmSize:    51292 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmPin:         0 kB
VmHWM:      3724 kB
VmRSS:      3724 kB
VmData:      520 kB
VmStk:       136 kB
VmExe:       116 kB
VmLib:      3732 kB
VmPTE:       120 kB
VmPMD:        12 kB
VmSwap:        0 kB
Threads:        1
SigQ:   0/55968
SigPnd: 0000000000000000
ShdPnd: 0000000000000000
SigBlk: 0000000000000000
SigIgn: 0000000001000000
SigCgt: 00000001800b7a07
CapInh: 0000000000000000
CapPrm: 0000003fffffffff
CapEff: 0000003fffffffff
CapBnd: 0000003fffffffff
Seccomp:        0
Cpus_allowed:   00000000,000000ff
Cpus_allowed_list:      0-7
Mems_allowed:   00000000,00000001
Mems_allowed_list:      0
voluntary_ctxt_switches:        2
nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches:     27
```

i am not sure, how can i fix this. can any one share some info ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to see if there are any broken dependancies ? Type the following command

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get install -f
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

Alternatively, if you are still experiencing the issue, try using the **aptitude** or **dpkg** package installation methods.

Last, but, lengthy, option is that you can download the package manually from the source file of mono-complete or by using `apt-get install -d mono-complete`.

This will download the .deb file under **/var/cache/apt/archives** along with the other required debian packages which you can install by using

```
`sudo dpkg -i package-name`
```

But please note that the installation might error out if you don't install the required dependencies in the system first.